# AJAX post jQuery to PHP $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have this modal jQuery AJAX:

```
        $('#switch_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var rowid = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
            $.ajax({
                type : 'post', // commented for this demo
                url : 'pars.php', // commented for this demo 
                data :  'id='+ rowid,
                success : function(data) {
                $('.fetched-data').show().html(rowid); // show rowid for this demo
                }
            });
        });
```

My mysql query:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM games WHERE winner='' ORDER BY amount DESC";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

My modal data-id:

```
<a href="#viewgame" data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"">
```

How can i do to use the var rowid like a PHP post? Something like that:

```
$id = $_POST['rowid'];
echo $id;
```

Comment: `data :  'rowid='+ rowid,`

Comment: still dosn't work !

Comment: What exactly is the issue ?

Comment: $_POST['rowid'] dosn't work ;

Comment: What is `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Comment: it's show me array(0) {
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand well this test your doing...
Your JavaScript `rowid` is the value.
The `$_POST` identifier is `id`.

Try this in your PHP:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo $id;
```

You'll get the javascript `rowid` sent as a POST value (named as `$_POST['id']`) via ajax...
 And returning in `data` on ajax success.

```
$('.fetched-data').show().html(data);
```

So you'll have to use `data` in your jQuery `html()`... Wich is the echoed text.

**-----**
**EDIT AFTER ACCEPTATION of this answer**
*(Based on your last comment)*

> So i have this query:
>
> ```
> $query="SELECT * FROM games WHERE winner='' ORDER BY amount DESC";
> if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {
>     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
>         $gameid = $row['id'];
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> So i want to use $gameid variable into this query:
>
> ```
> $sql = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE id='".$gameid."'";
> ```

I understand, that you want to get **THE LAST matching full line** where winner value is empty from games table.
No need for an ajax call...
No need for a second query.

Just do it:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM games WHERE winner='' ORDER BY amount DESC";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

for ($i=0;$i<sizeOf($row);$i++){    // This is the «size» (number of values) of one row, the last fetched.
    echo $row[$i] . "<br>";
}
```

You'll get all your line values echoed...
This will be the LAST matching line fetched.

**If you have many matching lines** and want all results, do it like this:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM games WHERE winner='' ORDER BY amount DESC";
$result = $conn->query($query));

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {     // While fetching, echo all values of one matching line.
    echo "row id: " . $row['id'] . "<br>";
    echo "values: <br>";
    for ($i=0;$i<sizeOf($row);$i++){
        echo $row[$i] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

**Notice** that this script, that I suggest, will enlight you about the `while fetch loop` possible results. You'll have to work a little to have it displayed correctly on your page.
;)

Comment: I tried like u said with php post but still no result. I don't need an jquery result. I need an PHP post so i can use befor while row

Comment: You have to understand WHEN your scripts execute. PHP is server-side and produces the client side HTML. THEN your jQuery scripts execute and call an Ajax...

Comment: So... Show more code... For us to understand what you're really trying. What you are sending via ajax now is a jQuery value... From client-side... Long after a PHP while row fetch of the original page load. Your ajax target page has to be another page... Different from this original page load.

Comment: I want to define the $id = $_POST['id']; inside while and to use like a global variable on PHP and i tought i can do it with ajax, but i can't find any solutions...

Comment: No. Like I said. Your ajax call is triggered by jQuery, on client-side, long after your original PHP script has finished.

Comment: Ok, i'm not a pro but how can i solve this so i can use POST['id'] as global variable?

Comment: Maybe this reading would help you : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/171210

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the right thing by `global variable`. A global can be reached on the «global» scope... So not only from a specific function, but everywhere in this particular scripting language... I think your problem is that you try to define a variable in a server-side language (that takes somehing like 0.01 seconds to execute completely and finish) to use it in a latter time in another script language, wich is client-side). So be more specific on the reason why you want to retain this value and how you wish to use it.

Comment: So i have this query:

     $query="SELECT * FROM games WHERE winner='' ORDER BY amount DESC";
     if ($result = $conn->query($query)) 
     {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
      {
       $gameid = $row['id'];
      }
     }
So i want to use $gameid variable into this query:

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE id='".$gameid."'";

Comment: Thanks for the green checkmark. But your comment leaves me perplex. I'll edit with something you could try.